# Is it theoretically possible to use a mirrorless lens for a smartphone camera?

Tags: lens, optics, smartphone

A example situation.

I want to take photo of a far away text for identification but my camera has a dead battery!

If I decide to use my phone (Just another 1/2.55 smartphone) and a RF (Or a EF-S) lens by putting the lens on front of the camera (Did I just invent amateur digiscoping?) how clear the image will be? Has anyone tried this before?

Comment: You would appear to be in a position to try it for yourself. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Too bad I am too poor to even buy a second hand EFS lens let alone a RF lens.

Comment: Related: [What are the advantages, disadvantages and effects of using a DSLR lens on an iPhone sensor?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14047/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-and-effects-of-using-a-dslr-lens-on-an-ip/14111#14111)

Comment: @mattdm good but I am was asking about using it without a adapter.

Comment: Charge your  camera battery ??

Comment: @AlaskaMan https://memegenerator.net/instance/62422068/dr-house-music-oh-my-god-youre-a-genius

Comment: quite sure charging your battery is faster than waiting for an answer. So is trying this yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hand-hold a small telescope or one eyepiece of a binocular in contact with camera lens of your phone. This method is called the afocal position. This works -- don't foo-foo!

Answer (score 3):

Beastgrip makes an adapter that may turn out to simply be a spacer. Holding a lens up to your eye, it is possible to “see” the projected image - I’ve no doubt you could get it to work with a phone. You may need a third hand though and maintaining the proper alignment without some sort of rig will probably be show-stoppingly difficult. Possible? Yes. Practical without a rig? No.

Responding to a naysayer comment:

The image below was taken by holding a 50mm f/1.8 in front of my iPhone:

[image]

Yes - holding a lens up to your eye works. So too does holding it in front of your phone.

Comment: no, holding a lens up to your eye (or smartphone) does not work - you would also need an eyepiece to make it afocal. alternatively, you could remove the original lens (from the smartphone or your eyeball) and replace it with RF lens in question ;-)

Comment: @szulat see edit. Yes. Yes it does.

Comment: this is using it as a magnifying glass rather than its intended purpose, but okay, you are right, it can be used somehow :-)

Comment: @szulat lol. Holding a lens up to a phone is already deviating from intended purpose. This whole op gets away from intended purpose

Comment: sure, removing your eyeball lens and poking the camera lens instead is not exactly the indended purpose, but would at least let the lens operate in its designed range and would let you see more of the world than just objects few centimeters in front of your nose!